# In the Moderna phase 3 clinical trial of the vaccine for COVID-19 what is in the placebo?

Tags: covid-19

Moderna has started a phase 3 clinical trial to evaluate if their vaccine can prevent coronavirus disease 2019.

What specifically is in the placebo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an [NIH press release](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/phase-3-clinical-trial-investigational-vaccine-covid-19-begins) the trial will use a "saline placebo", in two doses mirroring the two doses of active ingredient.

Saline is a fairly typical placebo.